# Jekyll markdown processing does not create hyperlink

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll

I am trying to create a simple website for documentation using github page using markdown documents.

The directory structure is:

```
root
 |-- index.md
 +-- _topic
       |-- doc1.md
       |-- doc2.md
       |-- ...
       +-- docn.md
```

The index.md file content:

```
---
title: TOC
---

{% for topic in site.topics %}
* [{{topic.title}}]({{topic.url}}] 
{% endfor %}
```

I was expecting the produced html will contain a list of hyperlinks since markdown uses []() for hyperlinks. Instead I see the following in Jekyll generated index.html:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>[doc1_title](/topics/doc1.html]</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>[doc2_title](/topics/doc2.html]</p>
  </li>
  ...
  <li>
    <p>[docn_title](/topics/docn.html]</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There must be a closing parenthesis instead of a closing bracket. And maybe you are looking for {{page.path}} instead of url.

Comment: Many thanks, that did solve my problem, but now url is pointing to the markdown file not to the generated doc.html files.

Comment: I think the problem was the bracket, am I right? Url should not point to the md file, but path do. Just change it back.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the bracket. However, url does not produce correct  result either because its not producing relative path. in github page this is hosted for a repo which produces an url like  https://<user>.github.io/<repo_name>/index.html. Any how here is github repo, https://github.com/kkibria/dev_cookbook, please feel free to fork and try :) Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A way to get the relative URL: {{page.url | relative_url}}

Comment: Nice! Thank you, that worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
 {{ topic.url | relative_url }}
```

which should give you the relative url of your topic